# Laravel Eloquent: get unique models between relationships

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a scenario like this:

I have `User` model that has an **OneToMany** relationships with the `Post` model.
I have a `Hashtag` model that has an **OneToMany** relationships with the `Post` model.

Recap: **ONE** user has **MANY** posts, **ONE** post belongs to **ONE** hashtag, **ONE** hashtag has **MANY** posts.

I would like to fetch only unique users records of an hashtag.

I'm able to do it in non scalable way (fetching all the posts first and then iterate filtering by user id), but I need to maintain scalability for large record numbers.

**Edit:** I saw a partial solution in Laravel docs.
Laravel eloquent has a method called [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique).

With that method I can specify the parameter which should be unique in query.

In my case figured it out with:

`$users = $hashtag->posts->unique('user_id');`

But I can't paginate query in this way...

Has anyone a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DISTINCT`

```php
$users = $hashtag->posts()->selectRaw('DISTINCT(user_id) AS unique_user_id')->paginate(10);
```

OR

use `groupBy()`

```php
$users = $hashtag->posts()->groupBy('name')->select('user_id')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to paginate your main model caller.

I don't know exactly if this is can reproduce your actual scenario, but let's see this example:

Let's say you have the model **hashtags**

So let's say the code could be something like this:

```
$users = DB::table('hashtags AS tags')
    ->select('tags.*')
    ->join('[posts AS post','post.id','=','tags.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate(5, ['tags.*']);
```

I don't know if your query it'll be very accurate, but for this, I believe the best approach it'll be you do a raw query, could look like it'll be costly to your database and the operation, but you can work around this approach indexing and partitioning your database.

Remembering always the eloquent sometimes even when we're building join queries could be more even costly to your database.

Since you're worried about scalability so the best thing could be for too could write a view to fetch all the data with proper indexing and partitioning.